# How to create (many address)/receive/send bitcoin without download blockchain?

Tags: bitcoind, node.js

I need to create a lot of address on my wallet to get bitcoin.
Check balance and make transfers.

I do not have a hard disk of 200 GB, can I use bitcoin without downloading the blockchain?

Need implementation on NodeJS, or at the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mkdir .bitcoin
echo "prune=600" >> .bitcoin/bitcoin.conf
bitcoind --daemon
```

And blockchain not more 600 MB